# How to access useContext in Axios interceptor

Tags: reactjs, axios, interceptor, react-context

I have created an Axios instance and a `notificationContext` to use in a React webapp.
I want to access the `addNotification` function of the notificationContext inside the `request/response interceptor` of the created Axios instance but since this is not a React component it's not possible. Is there a way to make and use this created Axios instance and interceptors as a React component?

**NotificationContext.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const NotificationContext = createContext();

const NotificationProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

    const addNotification = (type, title, description) => {
        const notification = {
            id: Date.now(),
            type,
            title,
            description,
        };

        setNotifications([notification, ...notifications]);
    };

    const removeNotification = (id) => {
        setNotifications(notifications.filter((notification) => notification.id !== id));
    };

    return <NotificationContext.Provider value={{ notifications, addNotification, removeNotification }}>{children}</NotificationContext.Provider>;
};

export { NotificationContext, NotificationProvider };
```

**App.js**

The NotificationProvider is wrapped around the NotificationList component

```
const App = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <AuthProvider>
            <NotificationProvider>
                <NotificationList />
                <Router />
            </NotificationProvider>
        </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

**apiClient.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
// import { useContext } from 'react';
// import { NotificationContext } from '../context/NotificationContext';

const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    timeout: 10000,
});

apiClient.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
        return config;
    },
    (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
        // How to access AddNotification here
    },
);

apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return Promise.resolve(response);
    },
    (error) => {
        if (!error.response) {
            // network error
            // console.log('Network error');
            // How to access AddNotification here
        } else {
            const response = error.response.data;
            // How to access AddNotification here
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    },
);

export default apiClient;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can export the axios instance
2. create a functional component
3. access the context
4. init interceptor in useMemo

Example (just for an idea):

```
function Interceptor({children}) { 
  const {addNotification} = useContext(NotificationContext)
  useMemo(() => {
    apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => {
      return Promise.resolve(response);
      },
     (error) => {
      if (!error.response) {
         addNotification()
      } else {
        const response = error.response.data;
        addNotification()
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
      },
   );
  }, [addNotification])
return <>{children}</>
}
```

and in `App.js`

```
const App = () => (
<BrowserRouter>
    <AuthProvider>
        <NotificationProvider>
            <Interceptor> // here
                <NotificationList />
                <Router />
            <Interceptor />
        </NotificationProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
</BrowserRouter>);

export default App;
```